# Node.js Nuget Package not Working in ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular application (using Visual Studio 2017) and I am not allowed to install Node.js on my PC.

I have created the default ASp.NET Core Angular project and installed Node.js Nuget package on my project.

When I build the project I am getting this error.

[image]

What is the correct way on using Node.js Nuget package without installing Node.js on the PC?

Comment: The Asp.net Core Angular project template will create an Asp.net Core application which contains a standard Angular CLI app, if you check the [Angular official document](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local), you can see that to use Angular, it required to install the Node.js on your local PC.